# Connecting the foreign key to an intermediary entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are 4 tables in my database. **User** (which has the role_id column as a foreign key), **Role**, **Permission** and an intermediary table named **RolePermission** (as the relationship between Role and Permission is M:N)

I want to get all the permissions of a specific user based on their role_id.

The intermediary table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE role_permission
(
    role_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
    perm_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT role_permission_pk PRIMARY KEY (role_id, perm_id),
    CONSTRAINT role_permission_f1 FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES role (rid),
    CONSTRAINT role_permission_f2 FOREIGN KEY (perm_id) REFERENCES permission (pid)
);
```

and the entity related to this table is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_permission")
public class RolePermission {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RolePermissionPK id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "rid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "perm_id", referencedColumnName = "pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Permission permission;
...
}
```

but when I'm trying to get this field in my **User** class, it returns nothing:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
private List<RolePermission> permissions;
```

The database works properly and all the entities including Role, Permission and RolePermission are working flawlessly too. But I can't figure out the missing link between the RolePermission class and the User class.

Comment: You said user has a role_id column, identifying its role. So User should have a ManyToOne with Role: a User has a Role. The RolePermission entity is useless, too: you can just have a ManyToMany association between Role and Permission. The association you've defined makes no sense: a user doesn't have role permissions. It has a role, and the role has permissions.

Comment: The database is already designed and cannot be changed. The "Role" database contains all the implemented user roles and the "Permission" table contains all the permissions. The intermediary table "RolePermission" gives permission to each implemented role. So in order to get the given permissions for this user, I have to retrieve the data from the "RolePermission" table.

Comment: The database is not the problem. The problem is your Java code. Read my comment again. I never suggested any change to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The M:N connection between the *Role* and *Permission* tables should be defined in the **Role** table like this:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "role_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "perm_id")
)
List<Permission> permissions;
```

and then the foreign key in the **User** entity should be connected to the *Role* entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "rid")
private Role role;
```